# Path not found at "Out\Foldername\" on unit test run in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am using VS2010 for development and unit testing. one of my module reads some dlls from specific folder (say ".\Plugin"). When I run unit test , it fails saying part of path not found "\TestResult\Out\Plugin". This is because I dont have "Plugin" in out directory.

How do I create "Plugin" folder in Out directory on every test run.